# Xamarin - XAML Grid UI overwriting on each other

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am creating a UI using a grid in Xamarin which I have put in StackLayout.
Below is the following code for xaml.

program.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="LoginPage.Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#3a4851">
                <Label Text="Identifications" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" Margin="10" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid x:Name="identificationGridLayout" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#3a4851">
                <Label Text="Deciles" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" Margin="10" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid x:Name="decileGridLayout" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I am creating the Grid header and data programatically.

program.cs

```
public partial class Page : ContentPage
{
    private LoadingPopUp popUp;
    private Repository repository = new Repository();
    private JObject jResult;
    private List<string> rowHeader;
    private List<PrescriberIdentitifcation> prescriberIdentificationValue;
    private List<PrescriberDecile> prescriberDecileValue;

    public Page() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public Page(string guid)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FetchDataForDetail(guid);
    }

    async void FetchDataForDetail(string guid)
    {
        try
        {
            popUp = new LoadingPopUp("Loading data ...");
            await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(popUp);
            //Get Identification Data for prescriber
            JObject identificationResult = await GetRepositoryDetailData(guid);

            var identificationdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PrescriberIdentificationList>(identificationResult.ToString());
            prescriberIdentificationValue = identificationdata.value;
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var obj in identificationResult["value"])
            {
                prescriberIdentificationValue[index].vcm_type_name = (string)obj["vcm_type@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                index++;
            }
            drawIdentificationGrid();

            //Get Deciles Data for prescriber
            JObject decileResult = await GetRepositoryDetailData(guid);
            var deciledata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PrescriberIdentificationList>(decileResult.ToString());
            prescriberIdentificationValue = deciledata.value;
            Debug.WriteLine("data prescriberIdentificationValue : " + prescriberIdentificationValue);
            drawDecilesGrid();              
            await PopupNavigation.PopAllAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
            Debug.WriteLine("error in identification loading : " + ex.Message);
            await PopupNavigation.PopAllAsync();
        }

    }

    public async Task<JObject> GetRepositoryDetailData(string guid, string entity, string filter) 
    { 
        try
        {
            jResult = await repository.Retrieve(GlobalVariables.AuthToken, entity, filter + guid);
            return jResult;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
            await PopupNavigation.PopAllAsync();
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Oops something went wrong", "Ok");
        }
        return jResult;
    }

    void drawIdentificationGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            rowHeader = new List<string>{"Type", "Number", "License State", "Sampleability","Expiration Date","License Status" };
            drawGridHeader(identificationGridLayout,1, rowHeader.Count,rowHeader);

            for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= prescriberIdentificationValue.Count; rowIndex++)
            {
              var datatypeLabel = new Label { Text = prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex-1].vcm_type_name.ToString(),FontSize=12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
              var datanumberLabel = new Label { Text = prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex-1].vcm_name.ToString(),FontSize=12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
              var datalicenseStateLabel = new Label { Text = (prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex-1]._vcm_licensestate_value != null) ? prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex-1]._vcm_licensestate_value : "-" , FontSize=12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
              var datasampleabiltiyLabel = new Label { Text = (prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex - 1].vcm_sampleability == false) ? "No": "Yes", FontSize=12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
              var dataexpirationDateLabel = new Label { Text = (prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex-1].vcm_expirationdate != null) ? prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex-1].vcm_expirationdate : "-", FontSize=12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
              Debug.WriteLine("data datatypeLabel {0} datanumberLabel {1} datalicenseStateLabel {2} datasampleabiltiyLabel {3} dataexpirationDateLabel {4} rowIndex {5}",datatypeLabel.Text,datanumberLabel.Text,datalicenseStateLabel.Text, datasampleabiltiyLabel.Text, dataexpirationDateLabel.Text, rowIndex);

              identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(datatypeLabel, 0, rowIndex);
              identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(datanumberLabel, 1, rowIndex);
              identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(datalicenseStateLabel, 2, rowIndex);
              identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(datasampleabiltiyLabel, 3, rowIndex);      
              identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(dataexpirationDateLabel, 4, rowIndex);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("Error in drawing Identifications: "+ ex.Message);}

    }

    void drawDecilesGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            rowHeader = new List<string>{"Quarter", "Decile Type", "Decile", "Rank","Organization Type" };
               drawGridHeader(decileGridLayout,1, rowHeader.Count, rowHeader);

            //for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= prescriberIdentificationValue.Count; rowIndex++)
            //{
            //  var datatypeLabel = new Label { Text = prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex - 1].vcm_type_name.ToString(), FontSize = 12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            //  var datanumberLabel = new Label { Text = prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex - 1].vcm_name.ToString(), FontSize = 12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            //  var datalicenseStateLabel = new Label { Text = (prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex - 1]._vcm_licensestate_value != null) ? prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex - 1]._vcm_licensestate_value : "-", FontSize = 12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            //  var datasampleabiltiyLabel = new Label { Text = (prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex - 1].vcm_sampleability == false) ? "No" : "Yes", FontSize = 12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            //  var dataexpirationDateLabel = new Label { Text = (prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex - 1].vcm_expirationdate != null) ? prescriberIdentificationValue[rowIndex - 1].vcm_expirationdate : "-", FontSize = 12, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            //  Debug.WriteLine("data datatypeLabel {0} datanumberLabel {1} datalicenseStateLabel {2} datasampleabiltiyLabel {3} dataexpirationDateLabel {4} rowIndex {5}",datatypeLabel.Text,datanumberLabel.Text,datalicenseStateLabel.Text, datasampleabiltiyLabel.Text, dataexpirationDateLabel.Text, rowIndex);
            //  identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(datatypeLabel, 0, rowIndex);
            //  identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(datanumberLabel, 1, rowIndex);
            //  identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(datalicenseStateLabel, 2, rowIndex);
            //  identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(datasampleabiltiyLabel, 3, rowIndex);
            //  identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(dataexpirationDateLabel, 4, rowIndex);

            //}

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("Error in drawing Identifications: "+ ex.Message);}
    }

    void drawGridHeader(Grid gridLayout, int rowIndexLength, int columnIndexLength, List<string> rowHeaders)
    {
        try
        {
            gridLayout.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
            gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection();

            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowIndexLength; rowIndex++)
            {
                gridLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            }
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= columnIndexLength; columnIndex++)
            {
                gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < columnIndexLength; i++)
            {
                var label = new Label { Text = rowHeaders[i], FontSize = 14, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
                identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(label, i, 0);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("Error in drawing grid header: "+ ex.Message);}
    }
}
```

}

> drawGridHeader() is common to creating Header for different grids. Data for the cell is passed in different functions and grid reference is passed to it.

Ex: -

> ```
> rowHeader = new List<string>{"Quarter", "Decile Type", "Decile", "Rank","Organization Type" };
> drawGridHeader(decileGridLayout,1, rowHeader.Count, rowHeader);
> ```

But after fetching the data, The Grid is over writing on each other.

[image]

I tried creating manual grid with row item and they are stacking properly in order but when programmatically doing it, grid is stacking upon each other.

It should been below the Label Decile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the last for-loop in `drawGridHeader()`, you're not referencing the passed in grid when adding the labels:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columnIndexLength; i++)
{
    var label = new Label { Text = rowHeaders[i], FontSize = 14, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
    // This references the wrong Grid
    // identificationGridLayout.Children.Add(label, i, 0);
    gridLayout.Children.Add(label, i, 0);
}
```

Comment: Totally agree. How did I miss that check. Thanks @Jon